# Inconsistency streaming behavior with Logstash - ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I have an index with several flat fields and several nested fields. I am trying to stream info from SQL Server through the Logstash into a nested field by a specific Id.
When I stream the data for **only one** Id then it passes fully and successfully without any problem. On the other hand, when I try to stream the data for more than one id - the info that is inserted to the index is partial for some reason.
**Note:** The query **is sorted by id**.
Moreover, in different tries streaming the data, a different amount of information is obtained.
For example, suppose the full info contains 15 rows. In one try - only 2 rows is obtained, but in another try - 14 rows is obtained, seemingly **completely arbitrarily**.
Does anyone have any idea what can cause this strange behavior? I would be happy for any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the [Logstash execution model](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/execution-model.html) where several workers can work in parallel and your events might be processed by different worker threads.

If you want to have a consistent loading behavior you need to execute your pipeline with a single worker (`-w 1` on the command line)